# Running two functions in parallel and for the same time

Tags: python

I have implemented a sampler and  a clock. I want to run the sampler and clock in parallel and at the same time I want the sampler to return it's end time to clock so that clock runs for that much time. These two functions are in some other module and it is being called from other module.

code for clock:

```
    def clock_generator(self, freq, end_time):

        time_period = 1 / (freq)
        clock = 0
        while time.time<end_time:
            clock = 1
            time.sleep(((time_period) / 2))
            clock = 0
            time.sleep(((time_period) / 2))
```

code for sampler:

```
     def data_sample(self, path, result_file_name, time_index, formatted_data, time_period):

        start_time = time.time()

        """perform few operations"""

        end_time = time.time()
        return end_time
```

Answer (score 0):

you must learn what thread is 
i prepare this one to learn [in this tutrial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU)

but for your question and if you know what thread is what mention [here](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-run-multiple-functions-at-the-same-time-in-python) can help you

Comment: but how do I return the parameter from one function to the other?